# How to get the process path using PowerShell.Create()?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am studying this and I have a question, how to extract the path of the process executable?

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace GetProcess
{
    internal class FileName
    {
        private static void Main()
        {   
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-Process");
            foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-30}{1,-30}{2,-30}", result.Members["ProcessName"].Value, result.Members["Id"].Value, "How to get the file path?");

                // How to get the process path (Mainmodule.FileName) using PowerShell.Create()?
            }            

            ps.Commands.Clear();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the paths like this:

```
using (var PSPath = PowerShell.Create().AddScript("Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path} | Dir"))
{            
    foreach (PSObject p in PSPath.Invoke()) Console.WriteLine(p);            
}
```

However, I want to find a method to get the path from `PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-Process");` where `ps` is used several times.

Thanks

Comment: If `result.Members["ProcessName"].Value` and `result.Members["Id"].Value` result to  valid  and trustworthy strings then use `result.Members["Path"].Value`. Note that you  could get `NULL` for some (system related) processes even in elevated mode…

Comment: Thanks. I tried this initially and I was getting an error ```System.Management.Automation.GetValueInvocationException:"Exception while reading "Path "```.

Comment: Membertype of both  `result.Members["ProcessName"]` and `result.Members["Id"]`  is `Property` while  `result.Members["Path"].Membertype` is `ScriptProperty`. However, each element in `ps.Invoke()` is of `System.Diagnostics.Process` type. Then, `using System.Diagnostics`  and  in `foreach (Process result in ps.Invoke()){}`   body,  there are scalar values `result.Id`, `result.ProcessName` as well as `result.Path`?